# Simple code regarding code to read from a struct pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, gcc

I'm trying to understand pointers so I did this code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct teste{
  int a;
  bool b;
};

void say (struct teste* a) {
  cout << (*a).a << (*a).b << "\n";
}

int main() {
  teste* e;
  (*e).a=2;
  (*e).b=0;
  say(e);
}
```

which gives me Segmentation Fault

but the following:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct teste{
  int a;
  bool b;
};

void say (struct teste* a) {
  cout << (*a).a << (*a).b << "\n";
}

int main() {
  teste e;
  e.a=2;
  e.b=0;
  say(&e);
}
```

I know that the second one is prefered but why the first one will not work? I think I did everything all right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine you ask me "where is the airport"? I offer to write the address of it on a sticky note for you.

On the note I write:

```
airport
```

This is not very helpful, is it?

```
teste* e;
```

this says "declare a variable, e, such that it holds the address of an instance of `teste` in memory".

But you haven't provided an actual instance of `teste` for it to point to; you didn't actually assign the address of something to it.

```
int main() {
    teste instance;
    teste* e = &instance;
    e->a = 2;
    (*e).b = 0;  // equivalent to e->a
    say(e);
}
```

The line

```
teste* e = &instance;
```

says "declare a variable, e, such that it holds the address in memory of a `teste` struct, and let that address be the address-of `instance` (&instance)".

We could also have written

```
teste* e;
e = &instance;
```

But it's better practice to try and always initialize your variables at the time of declaration, if you can.

The `->` operator is more-or-less syntactic sugar for `(*e).` -- it accesses through (dereferences) the pointer.

```
e->a
// is equivalent to
(*e).a
```

Where `.` is the member-of `->` is the member-through.

Note that `.` and `->` are distinct operators, which will become important later in your understanding of the language.

In this example, `instance` is a local variable and so is created on the stack. This means that when the scope ends it will be destroyed/go away.

If you need `instance` to stick around longer, or it is very large, you can allocate it from the "heap".

```
int main() {
    teste* e = new teste;
    e->a = 2;
    e->b = 0;
    say(e);
    delete e;
}
```

Explaining new and delete is probably beyond the scope of answering this question, I leave it to you to learn about them and their use.

Answer (score 2):

```
teste* e; 
(*e).a=2;   
(*e).b=0;
```

This gives you segmentation fault because pointer `e` is not initialized - it doesn't point to valid memory.

When you initialize pointer with some address say `y` - and then apply dereference operator, you tell it to retrieve value from the memory address `y` which you assigned to it. In your case, no address has been assigned to it, so you can't dereference it.

Make it point to a `teste` object, then you can dereference it.

Answer (score 0):

You never actually allocated any memory for `e`. You can either declare it on the stack, then pass it as a pointer by taking it's address using operator `&`

```
int main() {
  teste e;
  e.a=2;
  e.b=0;
  say(&e);
}
```

or declare it on the heap using `new`, then `delete` it when you're done.

```
int main() {
  teste* e = new teste;
  e->a=2;
  e->b=0;
  say(e);
  delete e;
}
```

Comment: what is the name of the operator "->" and why I can't use "."? Could you be more specific why one will declare on the stack and the other on the heap?

Comment: @Gatonito The operator `->` is the same thing as `(*).`, it basically dereferences the pointer. Compare the two examples in my post, you'll see that is the canonical way to access members or methods from pointers whereas `.` is the way to do otherwise

Comment: I created int*c; inside the struct, and when I try to access it with (*a).(*c) in the 'say()' I can't, and the compiler tells me to do it like *(a->c) so I thought *(a.c) would work too but it won't, so how can it be the same thing?

Comment: hmmm, I intuitively wrote *((*a).c) and it worked. Why?

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you declare a pointer, but that pointer points to nothing. So you get the seg. fault. You should assing a value to that pointer, being an address of an instance of teste, either declared or created in memory using new() or malloc()